# Back button for nested routes in Flutter auto_route (Navigator 2.0)

Tags: flutter

I have two routes, simple and nested:

```
    AutoRoute(
      page: ProfilePage,
      path: '/profile',
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      children: [
        AutoRoute(page: AddressesPage, path: ''),
        AutoRoute(page: AddressesAddPage, path: 'add'),
      ],
      name: 'AddressRouter',
      page: EmptyRouterPage,
      path: '/addresses',
    ),
```

The back button is only shown in `ProfilePage`, despite both using `Scaffold` with app bar. If this is the expected behaviour, how do I force show the back button in nested route?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `AutoLeadingButton` to the `leading` property of the `AppBar`.

You'll have to do it inside the `Scaffold` of the `AddressesPage`, like this:

```
AppBar(
  leading: AutoLeadingButton(),
  ...
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, `AutoBackButton` has been renamed to `AutoLeadingButton`.

Comment: That is correct, thank you for the comment. I’ve just updated it to reflect the changes